# How to restrict hibernate native query to only SELECT

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an application with a feature where user can make native SQL queries to database. Is there a way in hibernate to restrict native `SQLQuery` to only make SELECT queries?

Currently doing the query like this:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String, Object>> aliasToValueMapList = query.list();
```

I know I have an option to create a SQL user with restricted privileges but would be nice to have this feature as backup as sometimes I have no control over the DB management.

I would not want to use `sql.contains("update")` style approach as in some occasions these "keywords" (update/delete etc.) could be needed in searching the data.

Comment: If you only whant to do reading `update` or `delete` will never be used so you can do `if (sql.contains("update") || sql.contains("delete")) => KO`. 
By the way if you don't have full DB management, it's probably on purpose, so you shouldn't try to bypass that. 

The best solution is to become officaliy granted on a full db management.

Comment: And by the way doing `session.createSQLQuery(sql).execute();` with an  `sql` string coming from an user, is an very very VERY bad practice and an potential big breach in your software.

Comment: Probably you should create a new user and `GRANT` only `SELECT` permission to that user.